# ¿Como agregar estilos css personalizados a ng2-smart-table?

Tags: angular

lo que pasa es que estoy intentando cambiar los estilos que tiene por defecto una tabla hecha con el modulo ng2-smart-table, pero no logro hacer que estos se cambien, actualmente lo estoy haciendo de esta forma:

```
:host /deep/ ng2-smart-table .table > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
    text-align: left; }
```

Pero me manda error, y no logro entender del todo como hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: ERROR in ./src/app/@theme/styles/styles.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--14-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-4!./src/app/@theme/styles/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: expected selector.
   ╷
40 │ :host /deep/ ng2-smart-table .table>tbody>tr>td:first-child{
   │       ^

Comment: es básicamente ese

Comment: Cambia `/deep/` por `::ng-deep`  y remueve esto: `.table >`